# Execv syscall program not getting arguements

Tags: c, linux, gnu, timing

I've written this program as a more precise version of GNU time.
The idea is you call it with your program and optionally some args. The program part is working but the args aren't being passed properly.

```sh
> gcc -o time time.c
> ./time sleep 3
exits right away instead of waiting 3 seconds, sleep is called but doesn't seem to see the args.
```

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("./time PROGRAM arg1 arg2 ...\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    struct rusage result;
    pid_t cpid;
    int id = fork();
    if (id == 0) {
        fclose(stdout);
        fclose(stderr);
        execv(argv[1], argv + 1);
    } else {
        cpid = wait(NULL);
    }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, &result);
    unsigned long micro_seconds =  result.ru_utime.tv_usec + result.ru_stime.tv_usec;
    micro_seconds += (result.ru_utime.tv_sec + result.ru_stime.tv_sec) * 1000000;
    printf("%lu\n", micro_seconds);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: *The program part is working..sleep is called*. Are you sure? How do you know that `execv` isn't just failing since it would look the same as `sleep` returning immediately? `execv` needs the first arg to be a full path which it isn't in your example run. So I'm guessing `execv` actually fails. Suggest you add error checking for `execv` call.

Comment: I agree with kaylum If you need error codes you can read https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve

Comment: @kaylum removed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first arguement of execv must be the full path not just 'sleep'. Calling `./time /usr/bin/sleep 3` will work.

Comment: Note that you can also use `execvp` instead which will search for the binary in the usual PATH directories. So that the user doesn't need to enter the full path.

Comment: I don't really know stack overflow etiquette but if you want to post that I'll accept it. It's a better solution. 
Here's my modified program that work as expected using your idea.
https://gist.github.com/n8ta/00bd9b735f4b9efe7a031f9a98c9a93b